# Constexpr variable is not a compile time value?

Tags: c++, constexpr

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/constexpr-cpp?view=vs-2019

> "constexpr indicates that the value, or return value, is constant and,
>   if possible, is computed at compile time."

Additionally, [Difference between constexpr and static constexpr global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987571/difference-between-constexpr-and-static-constexpr-global-variable)

> "On variable declarations, constexpr implies const, and a const
>   variable at namespace scope has internal linkage by default (so adding
>   static does not change anything)."

Which I think means that `constexpr` implies `const` which implies `static`.

However, the answer for this question confuses me: [When and why would you use static with constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152096/when-and-why-would-you-use-static-with-constexpr)

It states that

> 1. "constexpr variables are not compile-time values"
> 2. "As it seems, we can benefit from static storage duration of a static constexpr variable in some corner cases."

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: "`constexpr` implies `const` which implies `static`".    No.    `constexpr` does imply `const` (but not, necessarily the reverse).   `const` does not imply `static`.

Comment: @Peter `const` does imply `static` (i.e. internal linkage). But only in namespace scope. And exceptions apply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're missing is where rigorous C++ terminology is being used and where it is not.

A `constexpr` variable is not a compile-time value because it is *not a value*. A variable is either an object or a reference to an object. Objects may contain values, but objects are *not* values. 42 is a value. `int i = 42;` creates an object named `i` of type `int`, and assigns the value 42 to that object.

The Microsoft docs are using vernacular language, not rigorous C++ terminology.

A `constexpr` variable defines an immutable (`const`) object whose initializer shall be a constant expression, and therefore the variable itself may be used in places where a constant expression is required.

---

> Which I think means that `constexpr` implies `const` which implies `static`.

Remember that `static` is an extremely overloaded keyword in C++, which has very different meanings in different contexts. The answer you quoted was responding to a very specific use of `static`: for namespace-scoped variables. In that case, `static` is unnecessary because `constexpr` namespace-scoped variables default to internal linkage.

But the other answer you cited is talking about *other* uses of `static`, specifically function-`static`. So to boil down that statement into "`const` implies `static`" is too reductive.

Comment: when you say namespace scope are you referring to global scope?

Comment: im pretty sure you arent but the examples provided https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987571/difference-between-constexpr-and-static-constexpr-global-variable are all in global scope i think?

Comment: ohhhh i get it now global scope is a kind of namespace scope