# constexpr static vs constexpr compile time

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

Imagine I have to instantiate a bunch of values at compile time that will be used to instantiate a class template, for example:

```
constexpr static std::array ints
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5
};
constexpr static std::array bools
{
    true, false, true, false
};

template<std::array, std::array>
class MyClass;
```

If I would want to optimize the usage of the MyClass template with regards to compile time, would it be better for me to use constexpr static arrays or constexpr arrays? Is there a difference in output code size or compile time depending on whether or not the arrays are declared static?

Comment: Did you try looking at the generated assembly? [When is it better to use "static constexpr" than "constexpr"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76695669/when-is-it-better-to-use-static-constexpr-than-constexpr)

Comment: Also don't forget that **"a constexpr variable at namespace scope is implicitly static."** So even if you don't use `static` explicitly, the arrays will be automatically static. See [Difference between constexpr and static constexpr global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45987571/difference-between-constexpr-and-static-constexpr-global-variable)

Comment: At file scope, you may have to consider `inline constexpr` if their definition is to be visible from multiple files.